# Can the amount of mass of a supernova star force the expelled material to return to the origin of the explosion?

Tags: gravity, supernova

Can the amount of mass of a supernova star force the expelled material to return to the origin of the explosion?Like in the case when a rocket lounched from Earth has not suficient starting velocity to become completly free from forced returning to Earth caused by Earth's gravity?

Answer (score 2):

A [supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) releases a *lot* of energy, much of it in the kinetic energy of the ejected matter. However, if the supernova leaves a remnant (a neutron star or a black hole) there is always some fallback of matter onto the remnant. This can be enough to convert a neutron star remnant into a black hole. From Wikipedia:

> Some material from the outer envelope falls back onto the neutron star, and, for cores beyond about 8 M☉, there is sufficient fallback to form a black hole. This fallback will reduce the kinetic energy created and the mass of expelled radioactive material, but in some situations, it may also generate relativistic jets that result in a gamma-ray burst or an exceptionally luminous supernova.

Not all supernovae leave a remnant. Eg, low metallicity stars with mass in the range of around 140 to 250 solar masses collapse due to [pair instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova). These stars are so hot that the thermal photons are gamma rays with enough energy to create electron + positron pairs when they interact with the electric field of a nucleus. That is, thermal energy in the core gets diverted into creating matter & antimatter. This reduces the core pressure, so the core collapses leading to further pair production in a runaway process which is so intense that it blows the star completely apart, leaving no remnant.

On the other extreme, core collapse can occur in a star that doesn't have quite enough mass to produce a supernova explosion, so virtually all the matter falls back. This is referred to as a failed supernova.